# How to update input value attribute on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

I have some fields in a form that send some data to an ajax request. 
I have a button that fires this function to get the data to fill in the remaining form fields on the page.

Save adding all my code, as there is nothing wrong with it at the moment, here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
<input type="text" value="corporate" id="type" placeholder="New Value">
<button id="update"></button>
```

The update button is used to make an ajax request to the database to get all the remaining meta data for that page. Which kind of works. However the id there "type" is the type of data i need (commercial / corporate / retail). Each type has a different set of meta data.

I need to replace the value attr when i click the button before the remaining functions for the ajax request fire off so that they take the correct data with them. So if i type a new value, it sends the new value.

make sense?

Comment: `</input>`?? There's no such thing!

Comment: It can make sense, the code you provided is not complete. Do you have a form? How you decide which value use as a type? I have the solution, if you clarify the question I can give you the answer

Comment: Sorry the </input> was just for the benefit of the reading view. I dont use it.
The Value is typed in using an auto complete. Perhaps the Rays idea of using a select field would be a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`select field`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) instead. This is what select fields are for.

Comment: Well, he didn't specify why he want to replace the type. Anw I would use [MDN developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) instead of your link.

Comment: Thanks Ray this has solved my problem. Using a select box didnt come to me straight away. I actually figured out something else helpful for the future with this. 
Thanks again.
Is it worth me posting my code on here or is it pretty obvious enough?

Comment: Sometimes, even bright minds can look over simple things so it's not that bad.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/o12d145e/)?

```
$(".update").on("click", function(){
    var new_val = $(this).text();
    $("#type").val(new_val);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this too. This is the angle I was trying to for in the first place but Ive used the select option to reduce the risk of users making errors on the form. 
Thanks Washington.